# Exclude records before a certain date

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I cannot seem to get the syntax correct on this.  What I need to is grab all records after Feb 18 2021.

I feel like I have tried a million things so far but this is what I have at the moment which isn't working.

```
@exclusion_date = Date.parse('2021-02-18 00:00:01')
@surveys        = Survey.closed.where('survey_type = ? AND created_at < ?','individual', @exclusion_date).order(created_at: :desc)
```

This still returns the exact same data as it did before I tried to exclude the older records.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to load records created *after* a specific time. That means the timestamp must be *greater* than the specific date. This should work:

```
@exclusion_date = Time.parse('2021-02-18 00:00:01')
@surveys = Survey
  .closed
  .where('survey_type = ? AND created_at > ?', 'individual', @exclusion_date)
  .order(created_at: :desc)
```

Answer (score 1):

In newer versions of Rails you can do this with a clever syntactic sugar using [infinite ranges](https://developer.squareup.com/blog/rubys-new-infinite-range-syntax-0/) `@exclusion_date...`, meaning all possible future dates.

```rb
@exclusion_date = Time.parse('2021-02-18 00:00:01')

@surveys = Survey
            .closed
            .where(survey_type: 'individual')
            .where(created_at: @exclusion_date...)
```